# Component is not getting installed at the time of minor upgrade

Tags: windows-installer, upgrade, installshield-2015

I'm having a product installer, in that there are a couple of features & each feature contains some components. In one component I'm having a desktop shortcut. So I just renamed that shortcut name and build my installer. So from then, the Minor upgrade is not replacing the files belonging to that component. From Logs, I'm getting the following message:

> Component: PQR_x64; Installed: Local;   Request: Null; Action: Null

And while Minor upgrade only, I'm seeing following lines:

> Feature: XYZ; Installed: **Advertise**;

I don't know why this Component and the others which present in the same feature, are not getting installed while Minor upgrade. Can someone please help me in this?

Comment: Is this the scenario described on Heath Stewart's [Why is My Feature Advertised?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2006/01/23/why-is-my-feature-advertised/) In particular, as he covers, look for `SELMGR` and use `MSIENFORCEUPGRADECOMPONENTRULES` to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may have renamed a keyfile for your component. This is not allowed when doing minor upgrades. Please review the table in this document to make sure you're not breaking any Windows installer [upgrade rules](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/MajorMinorSmall.htm)

There is similar [documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but I like how InstallShield broke it down into a table in the first link.

Comment: No David. I'm not changing any key file. I'm only changing the shortcutname.

Comment: Are there any other minor upgrade rules being broken? This is exactly what happens in this scenario.